# Why does line 11 fail?

Tags: kotlin

```
    1  fun main() {
    2     val listOfWords = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
    3        
    4     // Test1
    5     val test1 = listOfWords[1].toCharArray()
    6     test1.shuffle()
    7     String(test1)
    8     
    9     // Test2
    10    val test2 = listOfWords[1].toCharArray().shuffle()
    11    String(test2) // Problem here: String() doesn't like test2
    12  }
```

Why does line 11 fail?

Or, maybe a better question is: why is String() happy with test1, on line 7?

https://pl.kotl.in/y62nvnNfa

Comment: .shuffle() returns Unit, so test2 == Unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is long but I hope it explains a few things, and helps you work out how to solve these errors when they come up!

Here's the error you get:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public inline fun String(stringBuffer: StringBuffer): String defined in kotlin.text 
public inline fun String(stringBuilder: StringBuilder): String defined in kotlin.text 
public inline fun String(bytes: ByteArray): String defined in kotlin.text 
public inline fun String(chars: CharArray): String defined in kotlin.text
```

Those are the possible one-argument calls to `String()` and it's saying the arguments you're supplying (just `test2` in this case) don't match any of those signatures. It's the wrong *type*.

Since you're working with `CharArray`s and that's one of the accepted arguments, you probably think `test2` is one, but it's not. That's what you need to investigate. Like you say, `test1` is fine - so what's the difference here? What's different about the way you're creating those two values, that they'd end up being different *types*?

---

The difference is with `test2` you're calling `shuffle()` on it. You probably expected that to return the newly shuffled array, but since `test2` apparently **isn't** a `CharArray`, then seems like something else is going on, right? Better check [what `shuffle` actually does](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html):

> `fun CharArray.shuffle()`
>
> Randomly shuffles elements in this array **in-place**.

Two things there. One - it says it shuffles *in-place* meaning it doesn't return a new copy of the array with the contents shuffled, it just moves things around in the given array object. You see this a lot, e.g. `sort` (in-place) vs `sorted` (produces a new sorted copy, the original is untouched) and it's important to be aware that there are often two versions of this kind of thing!

The second thing is that the function signature up there has no return type. So it's really

`fun CharArray.shuffle(): Unit`

Which is another sign that it doesn't *produce* anything, it just *modifies* something. And it means that it doesn't return a value (except `Unit`, which really represents *no value* like `void` in Java). So when you create `test2`, calling `shuffle` on an array, the result is `Unit`, nothing, nada. And that's why you can't pass it to the `String` constructor.

There actually *is* a [`shuffled()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html) function, but it's only for `Iterable`s. So you could do this:

```
// converting to a `List` so you can run `shuffled` on it
val test2 = listOfWords[1].toCharArray().toList().shuffled().toCharArray()
```

but you might as well skip that intermediate array:

```
val test2 = listOfWords[1].toList().shuffled().toCharArray()
```